# Get started to launch google-cloud-ml with my own dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

I succeeded at executing all the steps [of the online tutorial for google cloud ml](https://cloud.google.com/ml/docs/quickstarts/training#train_on_the_cloud_distributed).

But since the dataset used in this tutorial is already a TFRecord, I didn't understand well in what way transform say my numpy dataset to a TFRecord one.

Then, I tried to create my TFRecord using [this a little bit modified code compared to the official convert_to_records.py](http://pastebin.com/YwXBx21V). What I understand is that we can only convert primitive variables to TFRecord and that is why the trick to convert a list of float to bytes is used.
Then I have to somewhere convert back my string to a list of floats. Thus, I tried to perform this task with either the line 97 or the line 98 [in my modified script model.py](http://pastebin.com/yZ5AXZCg).

Unfortunately, none of these attempts is working. I always get the following error message :

```
ValueError: rank of shape must be at least 2 not: 1
```

This is because the shape of my variable *features* is (batch_size,) and not (batch_size, IMAGE_PIXELS). But I don't understand why.

Am I trying to launch google-cloud-ml the wrong way or are there some more parameters to tweak ?

Comment: Side note: TFRecord file format of tf.Example is not required Google Cloud ML. Any valid way of reading data in TensorFlow will work. See https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/how_tos/reading_data/index.html. That said, reading files (vs. feeding; see link) can be more performant. And TFRecord files encoding tf.Example is a well-supported, convenient way to encoded multiple fields/features per record (e.g., image + label) on disk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error indicates a rank 2 (matrix) is expected but the value is actually rank 1 (a vector). I suspect this is because np.tostring() returns a single string rather than a list of strings.

I think that is somewhat tangential as I don't think your float-to-string and string-to-float conversions are consistent. You convert float-to-string using numpy's builtin tostring() method. That returns the byte representation of the data: i.e.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1.0, 2.0])
print x.tostring()
```

Returns

```
�?@
```

And not

```
['1.0', '2.0']
```

The latter is what tf.string_to_number expects.

You could make the float-to-string and string-to-float conversions consistent but I think a better solution is to just represent the data as floats. For example:

```
def _int64_feature(value):
  return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=value))

def _float_feature(value):
  return tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=value))

e = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
          'labels': _int64_feature([10]),
          'features': _float_feature([100.0, 200, ....])}))

feature_map = {
      'labels': tf.FixedLenFeature(
          shape=[1], dtype=tf.int64, default_value=[-1]),
      'features': tf.FixedLenFeature(
          shape=[NUM_PIXELS], dtype=tf.float32),
}
result = tf.parse_example([e.SerializeToString()], features=feature_map)
```

A [Feature proto](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.11/tensorflow/core/example/feature.proto) allows float32's to be stored inside float_list. You only need to convert floats to bytes if you are using float64. Your data is float32 so that's unnecessary.

Comment: I followed your advice and rewrite my code to create TFRecords [as you can see it here](http://pastebin.com/xJYQWp4P). Thus I adapt [the script model.py](http://pastebin.com/gwH9gYJK) to be consistent with the new typing. But I still get the same error and the print line 97 still return the shape (batch_size,) and not (batch_size, IMAGE_PIXELS).

Comment: I think you need to specify shape=NUM_PIXELS for the features. If you look at the doc for [parse_example](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#parse_example) the resulting tensor has shape (serialized.size(),) + df.shape

Comment: I tried what you just suggested. It results in theses scripts [script to create TFRecord with floats](http://pastebin.com/HYdx4u13) and [model script for floats](http://pastebin.com/smXkN333). Everything is running but [the result](http://hpics.li/3a1da05) let me think that I don't manage to decode correctly my TFRecord and end up with very small values as input. I can't verify this hypothesis since as far as I know, I can't print my data.

Comment: Have you tried evaluating the Tensors corresponding to the decoded inputs to see if they are correct? For example, in build_graph store a reference to the Tensor parsed["features"] so that once you have a TensorFlow session you can do y=sess.run(features) to get an array corresponding to the Tensor and evaluate it to see if its correct.

Comment: I tried what suggested @rhaertel80 in his comments. My problem was actually a bad combinaison input/model. Thanks for your valuable help !

Answer (score 3):

It might help to analyze both the output of read_data_sets.py and the output of parse_example operation in your model.py

**What read_data_sets produces**

[read_data_sets](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.11/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/mnist.py#L189), as you point out, creates numpy arrays for each image. They have shape [28, 28, 1] for height x width x channels (the images are monochrome) and in your original call to read_data_sets, you were specifying that you wanted the image data as uint8 arrays. When you call [tostring](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tostring.html) on the uint8 numpy array, the shape information is discarded and since each uint8 is a single byte, you end up with a byte string of length 784 with one entry for each pixel in the original 28x28x1 numpy array in row-major order. This is then stored as a `bytes_list` in the resulting `tf.train.Example`.

To recap, each entry in the feature map under the `features` key has a list of bytes with exactly one entry. That entry is a string of length 784 where each 'character' in the string is a value between 0-255 representing the monochrome pixel value for a point in the original 28x28 image. The following is a sample instance of `tf.train.Example` as printed by Python:

```
features {
  feature {
    key: "features"
    value {
      bytes_list {
        value: "\000\000\257..."
      }
    }
  }
  feature {
    key: "labels"
    value {
      int64_list {
        value: 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**What parse_example expects and returns**

[tf.parse_example](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#parse_example) accepts a vector of `tf.string` objects as input. These objects are serialized `tf.train.Example` objects. In your code, `util.read_examples` produces exactly that.

The other argument to `tf.parse_example` is the schema to the examples. As mentioned before, the `features` entry in your Example is a `tf.string` as defined above. For reference, your code has:

```
def parse_examples(examples):
  feature_map = {
      'labels': tf.FixedLenFeature(
          shape=[], dtype=tf.int64, default_value=[-1]),
      'features': tf.FixedLenFeature(
          shape=[], dtype=tf.string),
  }
  return tf.parse_example(examples, features=feature_map)
```

The interest thing, related to the error message you received, is the shape parameter. That shape parameter specifies the shape of *a single instance*, in this case, by specifying that `shape=[]` you are saying that each image is a rank-0 string, which is to say, a plain-old string (i.e., not a vector, not a matrix, etc.). This requires that the `bytes_list` have exactly one element. That's exactly what you are storing in each `features` field of your `tf.train.Example`.

Even though the `shape` property refers to the shape of a single instance, the output of `tf.parse_example` for the `features` field will be the whole *batch* of examples. This can be a bit confusing. So while each individual example has a single string (`shape=[]`), the batch is a vector of strings (`shape=[batch_size]`).

**Using the image**

Having the image data in a string is not very useful; we need to convert it back to numerical data. The TensorFlow op to do this is [tf.decode_raw](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#decode_raw) (Jeremy Lewi [explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40220107/1399222) why `tf.string_to_number` won't work here):

```
image_bytes = tf.decode_raw(parsed['features'], out_type=tf.uint8)
image_data = tf.cast(image_bytes, tf.float32)
```

(be sure to set `out_type=tf.uint8` since that was the data type that was output in `read_data_sets`). Typically, you're going to want to cast the result to a `tf.float32`. Sometimes it's even useful to reshape the tensor to recover the original shapes, e.g.,

```
# New shape is [batch_size, height, width, channels]. We use
# -1 as the first dimension in case batches are variable size.
image_data = tf.reshape(image_data, [-1, 28, 28, 1])
```

(NB: you probably don't need that in your code).

Alternatively, you could store the data as tf.float32 by calling `read_data_sets` with `dtype=tf.float32` (the default). Then you can construct your `tf.train.Example` as [explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40220107/1399222) by Jeremy Lewi, who also gave the code to parse such examples. However, the shapes will be different in that case. The shape of each instance (as indicated by the shape in FixedLenFeature) is now `IMAGE_PIXELS`, and the shape of the `features` entry in the output of `tf.parsed_example` is `[batch_size, IMAGE_PIXELS]`.

The tradeoff between `uint8` and `float32`, of course, is that the data on disk will be approximately four times as large for the latter, but you avoid the extra cast needed for the former. In the case of MNIST where there isn't much data, the added clarity of directly dealing with float data is probably worth the extra space.

Comment: I tried what you just suggested. It results in theses scripts [script to create TFRecord with bytes](http://pastebin.com/mzW8mXBG) and [model script for bytes](http://pastebin.com/vc09XKab). Everything is running but [the result](http://hpics.li/e18d9b2) let me think that I don't manage to decode correctly my TFRecord and end up with very small values as input. I can't verify this hypothesis since as far as I know, I can't print my data. Also, I don't understand where comes from the vector of length 768 since 28*28=784.

Comment: You can start by printing out the Examples in 'convert_to'. You can also print tensors in TensorFlow by using image_bytes = tf.Print(image_bytes, [image_bytes], summarize=1000).

I don't think you should need the reshape you have (image_data); if you keep it I would use [-1, IMAGE_PIXELS] to be safe. And in 'convert_to', I would remove the reshape you are doing to the numpy array -- it's basically a no-op after the tostring().

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was able to check step by step my variables and notice that everything were as I expected. The problem was that I unexpectably end up for all neurons in the last layer with negative values. Combined with the relu activation function, it resulted to a 0 gradient and 0.1 probability for all classes. Since my final goal is not to optimize mnist, I just changed the activation function to sigmoid and got acceptable results.

Comment: Just a follow up note: you generally want a logits layer that is linear; that feeds into two separate layers during training: a softmax layer and the tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits loss function. Of course, the layers leading up to the logits layer typically have relu or sigmoid activation functions.